# How to find the Position of Objects detected in a video on YOLO?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, code, motion-detection

Hi First of all I'm a real noob to coding and all. I found this YOLO and wanted to do something with it.

After downloading YOLO and running it by typing

./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights

I can successfully detect objects in a video but I need to get the position of each object detected like this example output

Video stream: 1920 x 1080
Frame number : 1
Objects:

Frame number : 2
Objects:

bus: 89% , Position : (0.032253, 0.110209), Height and Width : 0.063911, 0.072384

bus: 86% , Position : (0.237973, 0.090691), Height and Width : 0.074506, 0.068445

car: 99% , Position : (0.304282, 0.219430), Height and Width : 0.100312, 0.104738

car: 96% , Position : (0.452458, 0.125739), Height and Width : 0.044005, 0.061994

car: 96% , Position : (0.758392, 0.163063), Height and Width : 0.082789, 0.070389

So how can I know the coordinates of the objects detected. A detailed answer would be really helpful.